# Perl: Issue coming while running script via task scheduler (Windows) and not via command line

Tags: windows, pipe, tail

Below is the code which I am using (in windows(administrator mode)):

```
my $jobs=`bjobs -w | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f7 | tail -n +2 | sort -u | grep -i "_PV_"`;      ## Find out all the jobs running on cmd
print "$jobs is jobs\n";
my @jobsArray = split("\n", $jobs);
```

When running via command line, no issue is coming .(##cygwin is installed on my system)

But, when scheduling the task via task scheduler and running, below issue is coming:

```
-uThe system cannot find the file specified.
tail: write error
 is jobs
```

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: I don't know what `bjobs` is, but this kind of problem is usually related to incorrect assumptions about the current directory. The current directory is not necessarily the directory in which the script is located. That said, this seems a bit unlikely here. // I'm thinking it might be related to differences in the environment (e.g. the PATH) since you didn't run it from a cygwin shell that would have made changes to the environment.  This might be fixed by using `...\bash -lc "perl .../script.pl"` instead of `perl ...\script.pl`.

Comment: Note that you can assign the result of backticks to an array and you'll get one line per element in the array.

Comment: To debug this, do one thing at a time. If you run just `bjobs`, do you get the expected output? When that works, does `bjobs | tr` give you the expected output? Keep going until you find the break in the chain.

Comment: Given both the presence of “-u” in the error log (arg to “sort”) and my own experiences with sort, I’d say you have a PATH problem, and you’re not using the sort you think you are when running as a Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Added a valid path (with no permission issue) in "start in" option of task scheduler]

Problem solved by `adding a valid path (with no permission issue) in "start in" option of task scheduler`

With no path in "start in" of task scheduler, as script was running in administrator mode, default path in cmd would be coming `"C:\Windows\System32"` which might be having some permission issue. Adding "start in" path in task of task scheduler solved the problem as it changed the directory, which opens up in a default admin cmd, to a valid (permission error free) path (like, `cd "C:\\Users"`).